# Use a Pre-trained Network(1 branch) to initialize weights of layers in a Network with 2 branches in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, initialization, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a Multi Task Network with two similar branches and a pre-trained network with only one branch (which is also same).
I want to initialize the weights of the layers in the two branches(in my multi task network) with the weights of the layers in my pre-trained network.

Now, I can initialize one of the branch correctly by using the same name for the layers as in the pre-trained network.
But, I have to keep the names of the layers in the other branch different, and thus those layers won't take the pre-trained weights.

Also, I don't want to share the weights in the two branches. So, giving the same name to the weights in the corresponding layers in the two branches won't work.

Is there a nice way/hack to do this ?

PS: I would want to avoid Network Surgery, but any comments, explaining a nice way to do it, are also welcome.

Clarification : I just want to initialize the two branches with the same weights. They can learn different weights during the training phase, since they are governed by different loss layers.

Comment: do it with net surgery: it's only scary the first time, after that you are a surgeon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/E3GakB5DENE) by *Przemak D* is a nice hack to do the above.

1. give different names to the layers in the two branches and enable weight sharing
2. initialize the network and train for 1-2 iterations
3. then train the original network(without weight sharing) initializing the weights with the caffemodel obtained as a result after step 2.

The above is a nice hack, but net surgery is a better way to do this.

Comment: "but net surgery is a better way to do this". say no more.